# laravel Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

Tags: laravel

```
<?php
namespace App\Validators;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
class ReCaptcha
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $client = new Client;
        $response = $client->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
            [
                'form_params' =>
                    [
                        'secret' => env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET'),
                        'response' => $value
                    ]
            ]
        );
        $body = json_decode((string)$response->getBody());
        return $body->success;
    }
}
```

this code giving Error on server but working good locally

```
Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found
```

iam going made of this error .. how it is working on localhost and not on server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227080/laravel-class-guzzlehttp-client-not-found)

Comment: Heres a nice easy package by the way: https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha

Answer (score 1):

first check install and exist this lib in composer.json file 
 if don't install use this command

```
php composer.phar require guzzle/guzzle:~3.9
```

then

```
composer dump-autoload
```